# Alias in list comprehension and iterators

Tags: python

Suppose I have something like:

```
for e in some_list:
    fct(e.my_first_property, e. e.my_second_property)
    fct2(e.my_first_property)
```

That's a bit repetitive to write, so I could use

```
for e in some_list:
    p1 = e.my_first_property
    p2 = e.my_second_property
    fct(p1, p2)
    fct2(p1)
```

Still a bit lengthy. So I wonder whether there is some syntax that I could define p1 and p2 right in the `for ... in ...` statement, maybe like:

```
for e in some_list with p1 as e.my_first_property, p2 as e.my_second_property:
    fct(p1, p2)
    fct2(p1)
```

That would be particularly helpful inside list comprehensions, where I can not use the intermediate variables.

I never saw such a syntax, so I guess it does not exist. But you never know...

Comment: `for p1, p2 in ((e.my_first_property, e.my_second_property) for e in some_list):`

Comment: How is `with p1 as e.my_first_property` any better than `p1 = e.my_first_property`?

Comment: Your suggested syntax is not any shorter; you've just bunched up the code into one long line.

Comment: @khelwood: In the end, it's a matter of taste. But the question is about whether/how it's possible and not about coding style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) with `map`:

```
from operator import attrgetter

for p1, p2 in map(attrgetter(my_first_property, my_second_property), some_list):
    fct(p1, p2)
    fct2(p1)
```

In Python 2.x, `map` returns a list (as a opposed to an iterator in Python 3.x) which may not be needed if the size of your original list is substantial. Therefore, it might be more preferable to do this with a *generator expression* in place of `map`:

```
for p1, p2 in ((e.my_first_property, e.my_second_property) for e in some_list):
    fct(p1, p2)
    fct2(p1)
```

Comment: You should at least mention that in Python 2 `map` returns a list, which isn't needed here. A generator or `itertools.imap` (in Python 2) would be more appropriate.